# JSON data validation

Tags: android, json, validation

I'm looking into a simple and lean way to do JSON data validation using existing annotations, like `@NonNull` and others. I don't like to go heavy-weight with json-schema or the like, because I need it in a resource-restricted environment, namely Android.

I remember I saw a video presentation by somebody some time ago where he built something like that, i.e. he wrote an annotation processor (or did the validation on the fly, can't remember) that re-used existing code annotations that have been applied to his models anyways, but I'm totally lost to find the reference to that... does anybody remember?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it again, this was a talk from Uber and there they announced RAVE: https://github.com/uber-common/rave